# Importance of cyclotomic Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm working on a monography about cyclotomic fields and its ideal group class. But I desire some motivation to make it more impressive. Do you know some papers about their importance and some applications? The main text I found for this purpose is *mathematical modeling for next-generation cryptography*

Comment: I suppose one of the main reasons for studying cyclotomic fields was the quest to prove Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "importance". There are many ways to use cyclotomic fields. For example they were used to determine which regular $n$-gons can be constructed with straightedge and compass.

Comment: There is already a "monography" on cyclotomic fields by [Washington](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387947624). The class number $1$ problem is a nice "application" for cyclotomic fields - again, see [Washington](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4684-0133-2_11).

Answer (score 1):

Cyclotomic fields are the typical abelian extensions. The [Kronecker–Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem) makes this statement precise. It also gives a glimpse of class field theory.